# How can i pass active class through $router.push in Vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I am using router-link for menu list. With that, active class is adding properly on clicking the link. I have a button in a page and it will navigate to another page using $router.push function but the active class is not removed from the previous page link and it is not added to navigated page.

```
btnClick: function () {
    this.$router.push({ path: '/NextPage' })
},
```

Can i force set active class through this.$router.push() function?

Comment: How do you set up `router-link` with active class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `linkActiveClass` option while creating router object.

For e.g

> const router = new VueRouter({
>        linkActiveClass: 'active'
>       });

linkActiveClass is one of the route options.

https://router.vuejs.org/api/#name